# Why does next_posts_link and previous_posts_link doesn’t work?

Tags: wordpress

I try to create a next and previous page link inside my custom post type template. I thought it should work, but it isn't. When I check the developer tool, there are no links inside the list items of the `.pagination` class.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

```
<section class="page-title">
    <div class="container_12">
        <header class="grid_12">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </header><!-- End header.grid_12 -->

    <div class="clear"></div><!-- End div.clear -->
    </div><!-- End div.container_12 -->
</section><!-- End section.page-title -->


<section class="page entry">
    <div class="container_12">

            <?php
                $args = array('post_type' => 'roosters', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged);
                $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                $count = 0;
            ?>

            <?php if ($loop) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="grid_12 post-entry">
                <header>
                    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </header><!-- End header -->

                <footer class="meta">
                    <p><?php the_date(); ?> - Geplaatst door: <?php the_author(); ?></p>
                </footer><!-- End footer.meta -->

            </article><!-- End article.grid_12 post-entry -->
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p>No posts were found! I'm not sure what you're looking for.</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>


            <footer class="grid_12 center">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="prev-page">
                        <?php previous_posts_link('&larr; Vorige pagina') ?>
                    </li>

                    <li class="next-page">
                        <?php next_posts_link('Volgende pagina &rarr;'); ?>
                    </li>

                </ul><!-- End ul.pagination -->

            </footer><!-- End footer.grid_12 center -->

    <div class="clear"></div><!-- End div.clear -->
    </div><!-- End div.container_12 -->
</section><!-- End section.page entry -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here with your code

- [$paged](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) is undefined. You will need to define it

  ```
  $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  ```
- `wp_reset_query();` is used to reset `query_posts` (which you should **never** use). You should be using `wp_reset_postdata()` when working with `WP_query`
- You should be using `wp_reset_postdata()` before `endif`, not after that. You will be resetting the main query if there is no posts in your custom query
- When using a custom query, you will need to set the `$max_pages` parameter in `next_posts_link` so you should do something like this

  ```
  next_posts_link('Volgende pagina &rarr;', $loop->max_num_pages);
  ```
- You should not be using `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` after the closing footer tag. That you can just remove. It is totally unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
This ended up being the fix:

```
<?php next_posts_link('Volgende pagina &rarr;', $loop->max_num_pages); ?>
```

Original Answer, did not solve the issue below:
Try moving the wp_reset_query() below where you are using next and previous post links.

ex:

```
            </article><!-- End article.grid_12 post-entry -->
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <p>No posts were found! I'm not sure what you're looking for.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>



        <footer class="grid_12 center">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="prev-page">
                    <?php previous_posts_link('&larr; Vorige pagina') ?>
                </li>

                <li class="next-page">
                    <?php next_posts_link('Volgende pagina &rarr;'); ?>
                </li>

            </ul><!-- End ul.pagination -->

        </footer><!-- End footer.grid_12 center -->
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Hmm, this is’t working for me. My li’s of `pagination` are empty, the same as before..

Comment: Hmm, I dropped your code into a project of mine and it seems to work just fine...

However, it will not show previous or next if it is at the max amount already. So do you have more than 10 posts of that post type?

Comment: Yes, I have more then 10 posts on my post type, so it should work, but not for me...

Comment: Edit the next post link to this and it works for me now: `<?php next_posts_link('Volgende pagina &rarr;', $loop->max_num_pages); ?>
`. If you will set it in your answer, I can check your answer as good :) Thank you.